# Constructing numpy compatible memoryview interface for ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing

I'm currently looking into (manual & high dimensional) feature extraction on very large datasets. I am encoding n<sup>2</sup> edges in a graph in its simplest form `i -> j`.

I'm taking advantage of that features are independent of the `i -> j` relationships, and can simply be encoded with something ala `encode(i, target=False)`, `encode(j, target=True)`. This way I can encode a single graph in linear time (`n` time as opposed to `n²`).

This data is encoded into a tensor of the shape:

`# E :: (n, 2, d)`

with `d` being a feature dimension. Indexing into an edge is therefor achieved by:

`# edge_ij = np.concat([E[source_node, 0, :), E[target_node, 1, :]], axis=-1)`

My challenge is now that I'd like to interface into this ndarray as if it was of shape `E' :: (n,n,d*2)` ultimately so that I can utilize it to index into a weight vector `W` and compute a score, ala:

`graph_features = W[E']
graph_scores = graph_features.sum(axis=-1)`

There are more computations, which I'd like to do with the resulting graph scores, but this is solved if this is solved.

All my approaches have resulted in a lot of unnecessary array allocations, which I need to avoid to make my experiments feasible.

Is it perhaps possible to create some sort of memoryview? (cython is within reach)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question seems to be how to view an array with shape `(n, 2, d)` as one with shape `(n, n, d*2)`.  Since changing from `(2, d)` to `(d*2)` is trivial with `reshape()` I will ignore that part and focus on viewing a 1D array as a 2D square one.

You can use [stride_tricks.broadcast_to()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
line = np.arange(10)
square = np.lib.stride_tricks.broadcast_to(line, (10, 10))
```

This makes `square` a view of `line` (meaning it does not extra memory beyond some constant overhead), with all the values repeated 10 times.